Why does the landlord insurance not cover damage due to an "ongoing water leak"?
I have a property where the tenant has been living for few months. Few months ago, he noticed some water on the groundfloor laundry room, where water heater is also located. He cleaned it and ignored it. The water continued to appear so he raised it to the property manager who never mentioned it to me for almost 2 months. Eventually the tenant notified me. Meanwhile, the floor and drywall have also got damp as they wicked the moisture from the floor. The insurance has declined it stating that damage due to continuous/ongoing water leak is not covered. I opened another claim and the rep "advised" me on the phone that if i don't withdraw the claim , my premium will increase and my insurance agent will also be notified about it.
What are my options here? I am quite surprised at the condescending tone of the insurance company's rep.

You should speak with a lawyer. We don't know the details of your property insurance and we don't know the details of what happened.

Sounds like your negligence since it should have been corrected when the water first appeared or at the latest when the PM was first notified.

It's extremely reasonable that insurance doesn't cover things that you (or your agent) knew about or should have known about and did not fix.

You need to read your insurance policy carefully to see what is covered and under what conditions.
You don't mention what country you are in, but in the US insurance policies typically require that you or your agents notify the insurance company as soon as you are aware of damage. Furthermore, most policies specify that they only cover water damage from sudden, accidental, incidents. Damage from long term (> two weeks) leaks is typically not covered, even if you are not aware of it. From the insurance company point of view this is only fair, because the damage is much easier and cheaper to fix if it is caught early. They are insuring your property against accidents, not neglect. To be insurable the property owner has to exercise due care in the maintenance of the property. From what you've written, it seems like your property manager is the one who let you down here. They weren't responsive to the tenant, and they were indifferent about possible damage to your property.

In this case the property manager is the one who neglected it but this certainly is a failure to deal with a known problem, thus letting it become bigger.  I would be surprised at insurance anywhere being expected to cover this.
